# java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index

Tags: java, regex

I am using Java8 and would like to use the following Regex to filter an address from a string, but I get this error:

**Error**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 18
(\d+\s*(\w+ ){1,2}${(?i)\b(street|st|road|rd|avenue|ave|drive|dr|loop|court|ct|circle|cir|lane|ln|boulevard|blvd|way)\.?\b}(\s+${(?i)\b(apt|bldg|dept|fl|hngr|lot|pier|rm|ste|slip|trlr|unit|#)\.? *[a-z0-9-]+\b})?)|(${/P\.? ?O\.? *Box +\d+})
                  ^
```

**Code**

```
private static final String REGEX_ROAD = "(?i)\\b(street|st|road|rd|avenue|ave|drive|dr|loop|court|ct|circle|cir|lane|ln|boulevard|blvd|way)\\.?\\b";
private static final String REGEX_APT = "(?i)\\b(apt|bldg|dept|fl|hngr|lot|pier|rm|ste|slip|trlr|unit|#)\\.? *[a-z0-9-]+\\b";
private static final String REGEX_POBOX = "/P\\.? ?O\\.? *Box +\\d+";

private static final String REGEX_STREET = "(\\d+\\s*(\\w+ ){1,2}${"+REGEX_ROAD+"}(\\s+${"+REGEX_APT+"})?)|(${"+REGEX_POBOX+"})";

    input = input.replaceAll(REGEX_STREET, "<ADDRESS>");
```

Any help appreciated.

Entire Class:

```
package com.jobs.spring.service.replace;

public class ReplaceServiceImpl implements ReplaceService {

    private static final String REGEX_ROAD = "(?i)\\b(street|st|road|rd|avenue|ave|drive|dr|loop|court|ct|circle|cir|lane|ln|boulevard|blvd|way)\\.?\\b";
    private static final String REGEX_APT = "(?i)\\b(apt|bldg|dept|fl|hngr|lot|pier|rm|ste|slip|trlr|unit|#)\\.? *[a-z0-9-]+\\b";
    private static final String REGEX_POBOX = "/P\\.? ?O\\.? *Box +\\d+";

    private static final String REGEX_STREET = "(\\d+\\s*(\\w+ ){1,2}${"+REGEX_ROAD+"}(\\s+${"+REGEX_APT+"})?)|(${"+REGEX_POBOX+"})";

    @Override
    public String removePII(String input) {
        input = input.replaceAll(REGEX_STREET, "<ADDRESS>");
        return input;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ReplaceService rep = new ReplaceServiceImpl();
        System.out.println(rep.removePII("1234 Flex Road and 21 happy street"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove `${` and the next `}` after it, that is enough to build a pattern dynamically.

Comment: Thanks again Wiktor Stribiżew, that works.

Comment: Why don't you appreciate the effort others put in your question and accept the answer?

Comment: It doesn't allow me to accept the answer for the first 10 minutes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Java does not support string interpolation, the `${...}` JavaScript-like template literal  placeholders are not supported and are treated as literal symbols.

Since `$` means the end of a string and is a zero-width assertion, it should not be quantified. However, Java regex engine is lenient to the user and allows the usage of a quantifier with a zero-width assertion (you [may use `${5}`](https://ideone.com/MkuC5A) although it makes no sense, there can only be a single end of a string at a given position).

The major problem here is that `{` (start of a limiting quantifier) must be followed with a number denoting the number of repetitions and if there is a symbol other than a digit, anything but a number followed with `}` or `,MAX_REPEATITION_VALUE}`, the *Illegal repetition* error will show up.

So, just remove `${` and `}`.

```
String REGEX_STREET = "(\\d+\\s*(\\w+ ){1,2}"+REGEX_ROAD+"(\\s+"+REGEX_APT+")?)|("+REGEX_POBOX+")";
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/JmCx1h).